# Using Wildcard For Folder In The Mid Of The Path

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

So I have folder series like "ABC1000, ABD2000, ABE3000,...". With the input I have I need to copy a file from these. The information I have last 4 digit (numbers), these are unique per folder but since I do not know first 3 digits(letters) I need to use wildcard for letters. However I could not make it. And also I know that these all folder starts with "A".

```
While i <= lastRowTC
    pathPD = Dir(pathSource & "\ABB\A*", vbDirectory) & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add Dummy").Cells(i, 22).Value & "\getthisfile.xlsm"
            FSO.CopyFile pathPD, pathWE 
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: what does this return? `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add Dummy").Cells(i, 22).Value`  I am guessing you have an issue with your path and not the dir function.

Comment: It returns 4 digit numbers, like 1000, 2000,... 
pathSource and "\ABB\" and also that 4 digit numbers are correct. I am pretty sure. Because I am using same while loop for another path which in there only variable in the path is that 4 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Something more like this maybe:

```
Dim folderDigits, wsAdd As Worksheet

Set wsAdd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add Dummy")
While i <= lastRowTC
    folderDigits = wsAdd.Cells(i, 22).Value
    pathPD = Dir(pathSource & "\ABB\A??" & folderDigits, vbDirectory) & "\getthisfile.xlsm"
    FSO.CopyFile pathSource & "\" pathPD, pathWE 
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

...if the name of the folder you're looking for is "A" followed by two other characters and then `folderDigits`

Comment: This one is obviously better organized then mine. However it does the same. Now I get return of pathPD to see what is missing. So it is right now:
C:\...\1000\...\..
All dot parts are correct. Only 1000 part is wrong for path. It should be A**1000. (*: Are different for all folders.)

Comment: `Dir()` only returns the folder *name*, not the full path, so you're calling (eg) `FSO.CopyFile "ABC2000\getthisfile.xlsm", pathWE` which will fail unless the currentdirectory is pointing to the right place.  I missed that in my reply.  Edited above - might need some adjustments to the placement of "\"

Comment: I understand. Also I realize I did not ask it clearly sorry for that.
Let's say the folder name "AAA_???_XXX". XXX is number and I know and it is variable. And my code is working for XXX part. ??? is different for each folders but this value is not important for me since XXX is unique for each folder. I can find right folder with XXX. AAA is same for all folder. Now how can I retrieve path of this folders with correct numbers? So folder name is "AAA_???_100" with 100 I want to go that folder without comparing ??? part.

Comment: `Dir("firstpartofPath\" & "AAA_???_100", vbDirectory)`  should work.